# Update button error

Tags: vb.net

Our program when I click update button it updates all the data in the data grid view, what's wrong with our codes?
This is our code

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    con.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=sample4")
    Try
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con

            .CommandText = "UPDATE inventory SET product_name='" & txtPN2.Text & "',product_quantity='" & txtQuan2.Text & "',date='" & txtDate2.Text & "' WHERE 1"
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If result = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Data has been already updated!")
            Else
                MsgBox("Successfully updated!")
                .CommandText = "Select product_name,product_quantity,date from inventory"
                txtPN2.Clear()
                txtQuan2.Clear()
                txtDate2.Clear()
                txtPN2.Focus()

            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I see a lot of problems here, but you don't tell us what is the problem that bothers you now. Could you add some explanations here? Error messages if any?

Comment: When I click the update button ser, it updates all the data in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of errors here, both logical and bad practices at work.
Starting from the logical errors first:

What do you think this statement does? `WHERE 1` (I don't even know if it is accepted by your database but suppose that it works). It doesn't locate a precise record to update, it let every record in your table to receive the same values specified in the SET list.  You need to pass a key to identify a precise record to update. Something like `WHERE KeyField=KeyValue` where KeyField is the name of a column in your table Invetory whose values are unique so just one record is selected for the update

Second logical problem: `If result = 0 Then` this is wrong because the result of ExecuteNonQuery is the number of records updated/inserted/deleted. In your case the UPDATE sql updates always a record if it finds one. It update the record also if the values are the same as before. Zero instead means that no record has been found by the WHERE clause (after fixing it in the first step). Thus if you get zero as result then no record exists in your table that match the WHERE clause.

Now the bad practices.

```
SET product_name='" & txtPN2.Text &.....
```

This is a string concatenation that builds an sql statement. Wrong on many levels. If one of your textboxes contains a single quote the whole text becomes syntactically invalid. Finally a malicious user could write anything in those textbox and create an Sql Injection hack that could destroy your database or grab sensitive informations. You should use a parameterized query

```
 .CommandText = "UPDATE inventory SET product_name=@prod " & _
                ",product_quantity=@qty,date=@dt WHERE keyField=@kvalue"
 .Parameters.Add("@prod", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  txtPN2.Text 
 .Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  Convert.ToInt32(txtQuan2.Text)
 .Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  Convert.TODateTime(txtDate2.Text)
 .Parameters.Add("@kvalue", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  kvalue
 result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Second bad practice: Keeping global objects for connection and commands. These are disposable objects, they should be used in a well know pattern. Create, Use, Destroy to free as soon as possible precious system resources. Keeping them global gains to you nothing and you are at risk to leak resources. Keep global (or better read from the app.config) just the connection string and apply the using statement around the connection and the command

Comment: So, ser what should I do? Please teach me. In everytime I search that's what they say. Pleasse ser teach me step by step.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP phpmyadmin ser,

Comment: ser what's this error means?

Warning 1 'Public Function Add(parameterName As String, value As Object) As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)'. C:\Sample Application 4\InventorySys.vb 93 17 Sample Application 4

Comment: I was assuming Sql Server. However for MySql you just use the enum MySqlDbType instead of SqlDbType. Pay attention to the type you specify. It should match the type set on the database table. For example MySqlDbType.Int32 and of course you pass the value converted to the appropriate type not a string if the column expects an Int. And do not use AddWithValue. It is a shortcut that brings in unexpected bugs. Search on-line about this

Comment: I don't understand clearly sir, can you give some example?